# Casting Generic types in loops Java 7

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I have two different types of Sets that need to be iterated and one of the values of the objects of the set need to be summed. How can I do this with Generics, i.e without writing two summing methods for each type of Set?

```
private Double calculateFooScoreSum(final Set<Foo> fooScoreSet)
{
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for (final Foo score : fooScoreSet)
    {
        sum += score.getScore();
    }
    return sum;
}

private Double calculateBarScoreSum(final Set<Bar> barScoreSet)
{
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for (final Bar score : barScoreSet)
    {
        sum += score.getScore();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

How can I write the above two methods using Generics as a single method. Something Like:

```
private static Double calculateScoreSum(Set<?> scoreSet)
{
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for(Object scoreObj : scoreSet){
        //Some casting magic 
        sum+=score.getScore();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If it helps, `getScore()` method exists in both classes `Foo` and `Bar`.
Any ideas and suggestions are much appreciated.
Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a common interface, say `Scorable`:

```
public interface Scorable {
  int getScore();
}
```

And implement it with `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
public class Foo implements Scorable {
  public int getScore () { return 1; }
}

public class Bar implements Scorable {
  public int getScore () { return 2; }    
}
```

And then, define a method that can accept **any** kind of `Scorable`, using [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

```
private static Double calculateScoreSum(Set<? extends Scorable> scoreSet) {
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for (Scorable score : scoreSet){
        sum += score.getScore();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Which can receive either `Set<Foo>` or `Set<Bar>` since they both implement `Scorable`.

Comment: Also, there is no reason to declare sum as a `Double` object. A primitive type would work fine.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee: Indeed, was just replicating OP's original structure.

Comment: @João Silva thank you so much. this solved many other bigger problem too.